# opposite of memcpy to go from binary to text

Tags: c++, network-programming, buffer, memcpy

I am looking for a method that will do the opposite of memcpy when I make a copy of a buffer. For example, if I had this code

```
 _memccpy(szbuffer, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
```

The result of szbuffer is then binary. If I send this over from a socket to a server what can I use to convert the result of szbuffer back to text format instead of binary. I know that I can simply send it over as text but that is not an option for my assignment. Any suggestions?

Comment: This just copies bytes from one place in memory to another. What those bytes are doesn't matter and no conversion is taking place.

Comment: @Vince Abruzzese: memcpy won´t do any conversions. If the result is different, you hve something wrong in your program.

Comment: The `memcpy` function copies bytes, regard less of binary or text.  The opposite would be to not copy.  Why would you need a function to *not copy" data?

Comment: @deviantfan According to this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/ it says the result will be binary.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was using the memcpy to send it to binary and then once binary I send it over to the server but once its on the server I have a binary result instead of text

Comment: @Vince Abruzzese: That sentence means that pointer destinations etc. arent copied together with the address and things like that. Text is binary too in the computer, don´t worry about that

Comment: It says "binary copy", in contrast to value-copy. Some types (esp. in C++) have more complex copy-semantics, and a binary copy is useless/a really bad idea.

Comment: @deviantfan so if im sending it to the server as an array of chars it is considered binary?

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese It's composed of 8-bit bytes, isn't it?

Comment: @Steve Bytes being (or not being) 8-Bit has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: Ok... "The underlying type of the objects pointed by both the source and destination pointers are irrelevant for this function". That's probably relevant to the topic then :)

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese: Yes, because any data in your computer is binary. Don´t let Windows text-file-mode confuse you.

Comment: @deviantfan Ok in that case I won't use memcpy. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `memcpy` for conversions.  The `memcpy` copies data bit for bit from one location to another.

You want something like `snprintf` or `std::ostringstream`.  These functions handle data representations from internal to textual.